# Monitor resolution broken after installing Ubuntu alongside Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows, multiple-monitors, display-resolution

I have encountered a very specific problem after installing Ubuntu alongside Windows 10. I hope that i am right here since this problem theoretically occurs in Windows but i am very sure that it originates in the installation of Ubuntu.

The problem:

I have a Lenovo ThinkPad X1-Yoga 1.Gen Laptop (Intel HD Graphics 520) and a Philips 272b8qjeb monitor. Before installing Ubuntu everything was fine. Both monitors were running at their native resolutions of 2560x1440. After installing Ubuntu, Windows will only let me select resolutions up to 1920x1080 for the Philips. The internal display is unaffected. In Ubuntu both displays are recognized with the correct resolution.

What i have tried:

- The problem first occured after installing Kubuntu 18.04
- I deinstalled Kubuntu and I installed Ubuntu 16.04 (partly for other reasons) --> Problem persisted
- I deinstalled Ubuntu. Did a fresh Windows install --> Both displays worked fine
- I installed Ubuntu 16.04 again --> Problem occured again
- I have tried to deinstall and reinstall every display and graphics driver and Intel Graphics software i can think of without success
- I have tried setting a custom resolution in the Intel Graphics Control Panel but it gave me the message that the bandwdth of the connection is too low
- So i exchanged the HDMI cable which didnt change anything (This is also unlikely since Ubuntu works fine and it worked in Windows before)
- I have tried editing the Grub2 bootloader resolution with a grub customization tool in ubuntu without success
- In the grub bootloader command line the commands videoinfo and vbeinfo dont work and do nothing
- I have tried tinkering with the boot mode between UEFI and legacy but didnt notice any differences

I'd appreciate any hints or answers as I am at my wits end and google doesnt seem to have the answer aswell.

My config: ThinkPad X1-Yoga 1.Gen

- Intel Core i5-6200U
- Intel HD Graphics 520
- Bios Version: N1FET71W (v1.45 )
- 8GB Ram
- Ubuntu 16.04
- Windows 10 Education
- Internal 2560x1440 display
- Philips 272b8qjeb monitor (2560x1440)